# Debug/error log getting printed in the terminal while launching App on Linux platform

Tags: install4j

I have built a app using Install4j on linux. While launching the app the debug/error logs are getting printed in the terminal in which I have launch the app. The same is working fine on MAC. I have disabled the redirection of the stterr/stdout but I am not sure why it is getting printed. Kindly suggest how to stop it.

Comment: What kind of error do you see printed?

Comment: These are application related debug logs. We have log4j configured in the application so major of the logs are pertaining to log4j. These logs are fine but I don't want to print it in the terminal.

Comment: You say you have "disabled the redirection". You would need to *enable*  the redirection in order to not see this on the terminal. Also, I would suggest to configure redirection on the log4j level.

Comment: I redirected the error/output log to file. Now the logs are not getting printed in the terminal. Thanks for advice!